# MySQL Distinct function

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table of customer orders with columns email, firstname and surname.  I want to email everyone who has purchased.  I thought that using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email, firstname, surname FROM ...
```

would work to return all unique email addresses and first name and surname.

Comment: have fun with it. by the way...do you have any question?

Comment: what is the problem you are having?

Comment: it's ok, I was having a slow morning due to lack of coffee. Basically I wanted all unique email adresses and corresponding First Name and Surname.  All sorted now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
contact_email, firstname, surname
FROM
customer_details
GROUP BY contact_email
```

Haha, used GROUP BY instead :)

Comment: Here is another way to sortout this problem. You can use the following query: SELECT 
firstname, surname, DISTINCT contact_email
FROM
customer_details; this will also work.